# How to use commitlint to only allow commits from one email

Tags: git, github, husky, commitlint

I have several Github accounts and some of them are for open source repos and I use ssh keys for all of them. I'm constantly swapping workplaces and each time I need to be careful to set `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` correctly

We're using CommitLint and Husky

Is there a way to add a rule that doesn't allow you to commit unless your `user.email` and `user.name` matches the one I want?

Endgoal is to ensure that all commits, teammates' or mine, are always on the correct `user.name`/`user.email`

Answer (score 1):

You can try a [conditional include config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621480/6309), based on, for instance, the path of the repository, in order to include the right config `user.name/email` setting?

You can see an example in "[Is it possible to specify different names and emails per git server (using subconfigs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63240316/6309)".